# Weird unexplained Wifi outage

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have 2 WiFi routers, a Netgear R7000 and R8000.  The R7000 serves as an access point on the 1st floor while the other is in the basement.  Both are running DD-WRT, each signal is running its own SSID for a total of 3x 5 GHz and 2x 2.4 GHz signals.  I live in a remote area and only have 1 other Wifi signal I can see regularly.

My kids started complaining that the 2 Google Nest devices could not connect to the network.  I pulled out my Wifi Analyzer and could see the 2.4 GHz signal the Nests use without the SSID.  After rebooting that router, the signal came back for a few seconds and then vanished completely.  After more reboots, SSID renames, turning the signal off and on, I got no where.  I thought the router was failing...but then I noticed the 2.4GHz signal on the other router was gone as well. It was functional just a few hours prior.  Both devices were listing nothing connected to 2.4GHz.  I thought maybe something was jamming the signal, but I could see the neighbors Wifi and the Nest devices waiting to be reconfigured.

After an hour of trying to troubleshoot, everything started working normally again.  I could see both signals on the analyzer and I could see devices connecting on both routers.  The microwave was not in use, cordless phones not in use, etc (not that these ever gave me issues before).

What could cause this?

Comment: Murphy's law is my guess.

Comment: As above.   Also update firmware on your routers and restart them.

Answer (score 0):

Change the channel to something not particularly used. If there are multiple devices on channel 7 change it to something that is not commonly used. There may be other devices that are interfering with other devices.

Comment: When I said I was in a `remote` area and I could only see 1 other Wifi signal (at -90dBm), I was trying to head off this sort of answer.  They auto select the channel, I can't choose one.  During my experimentation I saw each use several different channels as they were attempting to come back online.

Comment: Remote doesn't mean much of anything. All electronic devices operate on a Radio spectrum, if you have any that interfere, they can cause outages. I never use automatic channels. You can manually change your channels on any Netgear router unless you have an ISP-issued CPE.

Comment: The R7000 has been issue free since, the R8000 continues to go up and down.  I figured out why only Auto was showing... very last post at https://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/7082 describes the issue I was seeing.  Now I have them set to 1 and 11 and see if that helps.  Maybe they were just auto switching to the same channel every time for an hour before it stabilized.  Though if they are really that sensitive, having WiFI in an apartment complex must be a nightmare.